# Why is EXE “not a valid Win32 application” using VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Building a static-lib CRTL program (ClCompile RuntimeLibrary is MultiThreaded) using Visual Studio 2015 and the default settings otherwise (`PlatformToolset v140`) it gives an error when run under Windows XP.

It's not about a system DLL having a symbol not being found, which is what I would expect, but a more dismissive “not a valid Win32 application”.

What's with the EXE that makes Windows XP not recognize it as being a program?

What exactly does `PlatformToolset v140_xp` vs `PlatformToolset v140` *do*, and what's the downside of using it?

```
<TargetRuntime>Native</TargetRuntime>
<PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>
```

It is a native program, *not .NET*.  It uses the Win32 platform (32-bit).

Comment: XP belongs to the previous generation of Windows, version 5.  VS2015 writes the exe file header to say that version 6 is needed, the version that started 10 years ago with Vista.  Surely you can guess what "v140_xp" might do.  Only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.

Comment: If I wanted to guess, I wouldn't have posted it as a specific question.

Comment: Your hits are different from mine.  I see answers relating to x64, .NET "full framework" not installed, and Java.